# About regular local rings and Socles

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let R be a regular local ring with $ \text{dim}  R = d $. If $ 0\rightarrow R\rightarrow I_0\rightarrow ...\rightarrow I_d\rightarrow 0 $. Then why for $ 0\leq i\leq d-1 $, the socle of $ I_i $ is zero? And why this is not true in $I_d$?

Comment: What are the $I$'s? I assume your sequence above is exact. With no conditions, this is not true. For example take $d=1$, with $0\to R\to I_0\to k$ split exact where $k$ is the residue field.

Comment: Mohan, I think the question is about an injective resolution. Anyway, voted to close as this is not a real question. 

Comment: You are right. this is a minimal injective resolution.


Answer (score 1):

I believe that you meant to say that the Bass number with respect to the maximal ideal is $0$ if $i \neq d$ and 1 if $i = d$. This is a consequence of the Gorensteiness of the ring $R$. I am pretty sure Matsumura's commutaive ring thoery book contains this result. In fact the vanishing part comes from the Cohen-Macauayness of the ring $R$. And $\dim_{R/m} Ext^d_R (R/m, R) = 1$ makes the ring of (Cohen-Macaulay) type $1$. This also is well known, a local ring having a canonical module is Gorenstein if and only if it is a Cohen-Macaulay ring of type $1$.

Comment: Youngsu, if depth M is $>0$ then the socle is $0$.


Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I meant to say Cohen-Macaulay type. Let me edit this. 